# Fitting an Image to a ROI

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, imagemagick, opencv3.0

I have an ROI and an image. I have to fill the ROI with the image that I have. The image should scale according to the ROI shape and size and should fill the entire ROI without repeating the image. How can I achieve this using opencv? Is there any method in opencv to achieve this?

Suppose this white section is my ROI and

[image: suppose this is the ROI]

this is my input image
[image]

Is there any solution using imageMagick???

Comment: ROI means Rect Of Interest. you shoul edit your question to to be understood.

Comment: @sturkmen Yes.. I have 2 images.. And one image should fit to the ROI of another image

Comment: @sturkmen Roi means Region of interest...

Comment: you are right sorry, but in OpenCV generally means a Rectangular area.are you willing only to fit rectangular areas of two shape?

Comment: otherways take a look at [this sample](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/xfeatures2d/samples/shape_transformation.cpp). i tried to run but it gived an error. maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32207085) will be helpful.

Comment: How will the answer look? I mean what is the result supposed to be?

Comment: Are you trying to fit the image or the fruit to the ROI?

Comment: @RosaGronchi Fruit...

Answer (score 2):

Finding optimal fit of one shape inside another is not trivial, but if you can settle for suboptimal result you can do the following:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

bg_contours, bg_hierarchy = cv2.findContours(bg_img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
bg_contour = bg_contours[0]
bg_ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(bg_contour)

p_contours, p_hierarchy = cv2.findContours(fruit_alpha, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

pear_hull = cv2.convexHull(p_contours[0])
pear_ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(pear_hull)

min_ratio = min(bg_ellipse[1][0] / pear_ellipse[1][0], bg_ellipse[1][1] / pear_ellipse[1][1])

x_shift = bg_ellipse[0][0] - pear_ellipse[0][0] * min_ratio
y_shift = bg_ellipse[0][1] - pear_ellipse[0][1] * min_ratio
```

(Heuristic) Resize the fruit contour, start with an initial guess based on the ellipses, refine using the contour (this can be improved but it is a non trivial optimization problem, you can look more [here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/pubs/PolygContainmentProb.pdf)):

```
r_contour = np.array([[[int(j) for j in i[0]]] for i in min_ratio * p_contours[max_c_ix]])

min_dist, bad_pt = GetMinDist(outer_contour=bg_contour, inner_contour=r_contour, offset=(int(x_shift), int(y_shift)))
mask_size = max(bg_ellipse[1][0], bg_ellipse[1][1])
scale = min_ratio * (mask_size + min_dist) / mask_size

r_contour = np.array([[[int(j) for j in i[0]]] for i in scale * p_contours[max_c_ix]])
```

Combine the images using the alpha channel:

```
combined = CombineImages(bg, fruit_rgb, fruit_alpha, scale, (int(x_shift), int(y_shift)))
```

Utility functions:

```
def GetMinDist(outer_contour, inner_contour, offset):
    min_dist = 10000
    bad_pt = (0,0)
    for i_pt in inner_contour:
        #pt = (float(i_pt[0][0]), float(i_pt[0][1]))
        pt = (i_pt[0][0] + int(offset[0]), i_pt[0][1] + int(offset[1]))
        dst = cv2.pointPolygonTest(outer_contour, pt, True)
        if dst < min_dist:
            min_dist = dst
            bad_pt = pt
    return min_dist, bad_pt

def CombineImages(mask_img, fruit_img, fruit_alpha, scale, offset):
    mask_height, mask_width, mask_dim = mask_img.shape
    combined_img = np.copy(mask_img)
    resized_fruit = np.copy(mask_img)
    resized_fruit[:] = 0
    resized_alpha = np.zeros( (mask_height, mask_width), fruit_alpha.dtype)
    f_height, f_width, f_dim = fruit_img.shape
    r_fruit = cv2.resize(fruit_img, (int(f_width*scale), int(f_height*scale)) )
    r_alpha = cv2.resize(fruit_alpha, (int(f_width*scale), int(f_height*scale)) )
    height, width, channels = r_fruit.shape
    roi_x_from = offset[0]
    roi_x_to   = offset[0] + width
    roi_y_from = offset[1]
    roi_y_to   = offset[1] + height
    resized_fruit[roi_y_from:roi_y_to, roi_x_from:roi_x_to, :] = r_fruit
    resized_alpha[roi_y_from:roi_y_to, roi_x_from:roi_x_to] = r_alpha
    for y in range(0,mask_height):
        for x in range(0, mask_width):
            if resized_alpha[y,x] > 0:
                combined_img[y,x,:] = resized_fruit[y,x,:]

    return combined_img
```

[image]

I Hope that helps.

(I omitted parts of the code that do not contribute to the understanding of the flow)

Comment: a sequence of functions presented lucidly. why is this answer not verified?